# middy-ssm not picking up changes to the lambda's execution role

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-ssm, middy

We're using `middy-ssm` to fetch & cache SSM parameter values during lambda initialization. We ran into a situation where the execution role of the lambda did not have access to perform `SSM::GetParameters` on the path that it attempted to fetch. We updated a policy on the role to allow access, but it appeared like the lambda function never picked up the changes to permissions, but instead kept failing due to missing permissions until the end of the lifecycle (closer to 1 hour as requests kept on coming to it).

I then did a test where I fetched parameters using both the aws-lambda SDK directly and middy-ssm. Initially the lambda role didn't have permissions and both methods failed. We updated the policy and after a couple of minutes, the code that used the SDK was able to retrieve the parameter, but the middy middleware kept failing.

I tried to interpret the implementation of middy-ssm to figure out if the error result is somehow cached or what is going on there, but couldn't really pinpoint the issue. Any insight and/or suggestions how to overcome this are welcome! Thanks!

Comment: This is a bug. It is caching the request and it shouldn't be. I've pushed a fix, will be in the next release. Thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as pointed out by Will in the comments, this turned out to be a bug.